# mysqli_fetch_field() outputs field names multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the column names from my database and i am able to do this with the `mysqli_fetch_field()`function, however my issue is that it outputs the column names several times when i only want it to output each of the column names once. I have my `$field_info` variable set to the that function that takes the parameter `$result` which is set to my query and all of that is placed into my while loop. I have a feeling that this might be caused by my while loop? but i am not too sure.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM bodyshops_master_network";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{

// print the column names as the headers of a table 
while ($field_info = mysqli_fetch_field($result))
{
    printf("postcodes_covered %s\n", $field_info->postcodes_covered);
    printf("dealer_code %s\n", $field_info->dealer_code);
    printf("dealer_name %s\n", $field_info->dealer_name);
    printf("bodyshop_id %s\n", $field_info->bodyshop_id);
    printf("bodyshop_name %s\n", $field_info->bodyshop_name);
    printf("address1 %s\n", $field_info->address1);
    printf("address2 %s\n", $field_info->address2);
    printf("address3 %s\n", $field_info->address3);
    printf("address4 %s\n", $field_info->address4);
    printf("address5 %s\n", $field_info->address5);
    printf("postcode %s\n", $field_info->postcode);
    printf("BO_tel %s\n", $field_info->BO_tel);
    printf("BO_email %s\n", $field_info->BO_email);
    printf("BC_name %s\n", $field_info->BC_name);
    printf("equity_contract %s\n", $field_info->equity_contract);

}
```

Comment: Does the repetition have a pattern like every column repeats 2 times

Comment: it has randomly printed it out 15 times. So each line contains postcodes_covered, dealer_code, dealer_name ...etc and that is printed 15 times

Comment: oh basically its printing the set of column names by the number of elements there are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
// making a query
$query = "SELECT * FROM bodyshops_master_network";

// firing a query and getting the resource in $result variable
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$i = 0;

// loop all fields
while ($i < mysqli_field_count($result)) {

    // fetching field information. Index of the field is given by $i
    $meta = mysqli_fetch_field($result, $i);
    // display information for each field here
    .
    .
    //
    $i++;
}
```

Refer **[mysqli_field_count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.field-count.php)** and **[mysqli_fetch_field](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php)** of official documentation

Comment: would you be able to explain your code to me please as i am relatively new to php and mysql

Comment: @user3009232: Sure. I will edit my answer and add comments to it so that you can understand.